# Getting unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405) error while access /refresh actuator is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I created one @RestController class and trying to use /refresh actuator values from config server.
/refresh actuatoris not working. I am getting below error. Spring boot version is 2.0.0-Release. I can not upgrade spring boot version.

http://localhost:8888/secondservice/admin/refresh

```
    Whitelabel Error Page
    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

    Thu Jan 23 10:16:10 EST 2020
    ***There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
    Request method 'GET' not supported***
```

Dependency:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Foo.Class

```
    @RefreshScope
    @RestController
    public class Foo {


        @Value("${welcome.message}")
        private String personName;

        @RequestMapping(value ="/", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String greet(){
            return "hello " + "POST "+ personName;
        }

    }
```

bootstrap.yml

```
    server:
      port: 8888 
    spring:
      application:
        name: secondservice  
      cloud:
        config:
          uri: http://localhost:8890/configserverdemo
          fail-fast: false
          enabled: true
          server:
            bootstrap: true
    management:
      context-path: /admin
      security:
        enabled: false
      endpoints:
        web:
          exposure:
            include: "*"
      endpoint:
        refresh:
          enabled: true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
>       Request method 'GET' not supported

The above error means that **HTTP GET** is not supported on that particular endpoint.

To refresh the config from spring config server you need to make an **HTTP POST** request on `http://localhost:8888/secondservice/admin/refresh`

Below is from the Spring [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/#_reading_configuration_from_the_config_server_by_using_the_config_client#_test_the_application)

> You can invoke the refresh Actuator endpoint by sending an empty HTTP POST to the client’s refresh endpoint

To make the HTTP POST request, you can use any HTTP client, eg [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [cURL](https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-post). To use cURL, you can run the below command on a terminal

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8888/secondservice/admin/refresh
```

Comment: I am already using "RequestMethod.POST" on @RequestMapping. how will i make HTTP Post request?

Comment: @user84 The `RequestMethod.POST` that you added is on the `greet()` method is for that particular endpoint and not for refreshing the config. The refresh endpoint is added by Spring, and the POST request can be made using any http client. You can even do it using curl on the terminal like `curl -X POST http://localhost:8888/secondservice/admin/refresh`